# select a table from a database in R

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr, dbplyr, qubole

I am using dbplyr to select a table from a remote database using Rstudio. I connected with Spark in the server using livy. It shows me the databases I have but when I try to access one of the tables in one of the schemas, it fails.

> src_databases(sc) # sc is the spark connection via livy. It connects successfully and shows all the databases I have.

Next, I want to connect to a table in one of the databases using [dbplyr's in_schema function](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/in_schema.html)

> browser = tbl(sc, in_schema('database_name', 'table_name'))

but it gives the error message below. What could be the problem? The Spark I am using is in Qubole. I also tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806426/access-table-in-other-than-default-scheme-database-from-sparklyr) but it did not work for me.

> Error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_13.getAllPartitions(HiveShim.scala:434) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$getPartitions$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:527) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$getPartitions$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:524) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:263) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:210) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:209) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:252) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.getPartitions(HiveClientImpl.scala:524) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.MetastoreRelation.allPartitions$lzycompute(MetastoreRelation.scala:150) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.MetastoreRelation.allPartitions(MetastoreRelation.scala:150) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.MetastoreRelation.getHiveQlPartitions(MetastoreRelation.scala:162) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveMetastoreCatalog$$convertToLogicalRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:256) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog$ParquetConversions$.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveMetastoreCatalog$ParquetConversions$$convertToParquetRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:376) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog$ParquetConversions$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:399) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog$ParquetConversions$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:384) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:301) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:301) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:300) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:321) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:179) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:319) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:298) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:298) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$5.apply(TreeNode.scala:321) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:179) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:319) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:298) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog$ParquetConversions$.apply(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:384) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog$ParquetConversions$.apply(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:363) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82) at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124) at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74) at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:65) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:63) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:49) at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.(Dataset.scala:161) at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.(Dataset.scala:167) at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:65) at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:583) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at $line43.$read$$iw$$iw$Invoke.invoke(:144) at $line49.$read$$iw$$iw$StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(:140) at $line49.$read$$iw$$iw$StreamHandler.read(:83) at $line112.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$LivyUtils$.invokeFromBase64(:158) at $line172.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:136) at $line172.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:141) at $line172.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:143) at $line172.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:145) at $line172.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:147) at $line172.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:149) at $line172.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:151) at $line172.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:153) at $line172.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:155) at $line172.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:157) at $line172.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:159) at $line172.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.(:161) at $line172.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw

Comment: The exception you quote suggests you've imported `rlang` or `purr` and `rlang::invoke` shades `sparklyr::invoke`. Try using fully qualified name.

Comment: (I [just answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51385057/8371915) a question describing the same problem)

Comment: [This might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21138751/8371915)